# The radio button value cannot be inserted into database. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, radio-button

I'm building a survey app where the user can select only one of these options 1 = Strongly Disagree, 2 = Strongly Agree, 3 = Neither Agree or Disagree, 4 = Agree, 5 = Strongly Agree.

I'm using Laravel where principal_questionnaires is the parent table and checklists is the child table.
What I want to achieve is when the user checks one of the radio button, the single digit whether 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 must be inserted as a value into checklists table in checklist column. But when I click submit, the checklist value returns null. I'm struggling for this problem for 3 weeks. I did lots of research for this within 3 weeks but there's no positif outcome. Can any one helps to solve this?

Below is my code:

Questionnaire Eloquent Model

```
<?php
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  //questionnaire model
  class PrincipalQuestionnaire extends Model{

  protected $fillable = ['questionnaires'];

  protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime',
  ];

   //questionnaire has many checklists
  public function surveyChecklists() {
    return $this->hasMany(SurveyChecklist::class, 'principal_questionnaire_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Checklist Eloquent Model

```
class SurveyChecklist extends Model
{

public $table = 'survey_checklists';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'principal_questionnaire_id', 'checklist'
];

protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime',
];

//checklists belong to a questionnaire
public function principalQuestionnaire()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PrincipalQuestionnaire::class, 'principal_questionnaire_id');
}
```

Controller's store action

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $form_data = array(
        'user_id' =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'principal_questionnaire_id' => $request->principal_questionnaire_id,
        'checklist' => $request->checklist
    );
    
    SurveyChecklist::create($form_data);
```

Blade page

```
 @foreach($principal->principalQuestionnaires as $mysurvey)
     <div class="row survey-row">
       <div class="col-md-7">
          <p>
             {{ $mysurvey->questionnaires }}
          </p>
       </div>
                                        
       <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" value="1" class="form- 
             check-input" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ old('user_id', isset($questionnire) ? 
             $questionnire->user_id : '') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="principal_questionnaire_id" value="{{ $mysurvey->id }}">
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" value="2" class="form- 
             check-input" required>
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="radio-inline">
           <input type="radio" name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" value="3" class="form- 
           check-input" required>
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" value="4" class="form- 
              check-input" required>
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="radio-inline">
             <input type="radio" name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" value="5" class="form- 
              check-input" required>
           </label>
       </div>
     </div>
   @endforeach
```

Page on the browser

[image]

This is the exception thrown:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'checklist' cannot be null (SQL: insert 
into `survey_checklists` (`user_id`, `principal_questionnaire_id`, `checklist`, `updated_at`, 
`created_at`) values (1, 39, ?, 2021-02-20 10:59:12, 2021-02-20 10:59:12))
```

Comment: change name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}" to name="checklist". thats all you need to do

Comment: I tried as you suggested but now the radio's behavior changes. It now checks only once for the entire application. And left other rows empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
 name="checklist{{ $mysurvey->id }}"
```

When the html is loaded, the name becomes "checklist1" and when you hit submit, you don't have input with name checklist because all your inputs became checklist1, checklist2 etc.

To fix this try for the input:

```
 <input type="radio" name="checklist" value="{{ $mysurvey->id }}" class="form- 
          check-input" required>
```

Also if you want to have multiple checks, you need to make the checklist as an array:

```
    <input type="radio" name="checklist[{{ $mysurvey->id }}]" value="{{ $mysurvey->id }}" class="form- 
          check-input" required>
```

and after submit, in controller loop with `foreach` thru `$request->checklist` to save selected checklists

Comment: <input type="radio" name="checklist" value="{{ $mysurvey->id }}" class="form- 
          check-input" required> This code will exhibit wrong behavior inside of the foreach loop. This is what I answered @Masih Ansari

Comment: If you want to loop thru it, make it as an array as I have demonstrated in the second example. If checklist could be only 1 value, you don't need an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to work on your controller. It seems like `'checklist'=>$request->checklist` does not work. I am not very experienced with Laravel but I guess that is the problem right there hence returning null.

So try something like `'checklist'=>$request['checklist'.$mysurvey->id]`

So the store function becomes

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $form_data = array(
        'user_id' =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'principal_questionnaire_id' => $request->principal_questionnaire_id,
        'checklist'=>$request['checklist'.$mysurvey->id]
    );
    
    SurveyChecklist::create($form_data);
}
```